# Как поменять формат вывода даты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

на 12 апреля 2021 ( к примеру)

[http://jsfiddle.net/swecad8u/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите значение `dateFormat: 'd M yy'`

```
  $(function(){
        var $myDate = $('#myDate');
        $myDate.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'd M yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'd M yy');                
            }
        });
    });
```

Для кириллицы:

```
$(function () {
    var $myDate = $('#myDate');
    $myDate.datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd M yy',
        monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь' ],
        monthNamesShort: ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Мар', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июн', 'Июл', 'Авг', 'Сен', 'Окт', 'Ноя', 'Дек'],
        dayNames: ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'],
        dayNamesShort: ['вск', 'пнд', 'втр', 'срд', 'чтв', 'птн', 'сбт'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'd M yy');
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: спасибо. а если нужно в засимости от языка нужный перевод месяца - это уже бэкендер?

Comment: Бэкенд тут ни при чём :)  вам необходимо в `datapicker` указать, покажу пример для русского, дальше сами.

Comment: спасибо, но не совсем об этом речь. человек нажимает на русс - месяцы будут на русском. англ - на английском. Или как раз к этому вы скинули?

Comment: Ваш вопрос о том, "Как поменять формат вывода даты?" я показал пример + показал как можно перевести названия. Остальное вам надо сделать, создать несколько массивов с названиями в JS файле и подставлять  в зависимости от активного языка

Comment: да, спасибо огромное)